# In JAWS and Chrome the screen reader is not announcing the current list item/current section

Tags: accessibility

I have ran into issue in Jaws and chrome that screen reader is not notifying current item
Usually in NVDA it will announce as "current"
And this issue is obseverd in sliders and curosels whenever we are clicking on the dot of the slider the slide will change and focus is on the required dot but not notifying it as current item

And also same issue is there in the sub sections also

i have shared the required code can anyone guide me on this

```html
<nav aria-label="Settings" data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-23f2CQ">
                <ul class="tab-list" data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-gx3A3Q">

                    <li data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-eyXeHn" class="au-target tab-listitem" au-target-id="182">
                        <a class="tab-link au-target" href="javascript:void(0)" click.delegate="activateStep(eachStep.stepName)" data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-lKVp3L" au-target-id="183" id="accountSettings" aria-current="false">
                            <span data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-MK4WZK">
                                Account settings
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li><li data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-eyXeHn" class="au-target tab-listitem" au-target-id="182">
                        <a class="tab-link au-target" href="javascript:void(0)" click.delegate="activateStep(eachStep.stepName)" data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-lKVp3L" au-target-id="183" id="personalisationSettings" aria-current="false">
                            <span data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-MK4WZK">
                                Profile Information
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li><li data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-eyXeHn" class="au-target tab-listitem" au-target-id="182">
                        <a class="tab-link au-target" href="javascript:void(0)" click.delegate="activateStep(eachStep.stepName)" data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-lKVp3L" au-target-id="183" id="myApplications" aria-current="false">
                            <span data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-MK4WZK">
                                My Applications
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li><li data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-eyXeHn" class="au-target tab-listitem" au-target-id="182">
                        <a class="tab-link au-target" href="javascript:void(0)" click.delegate="activateStep(eachStep.stepName)" data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-lKVp3L" au-target-id="183" id="jobAlerts" aria-current="false">
                            <span data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-MK4WZK">
                                Job Alerts
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li><li data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-eyXeHn" class="au-target tab-listitem active" au-target-id="182">
                        <a class="tab-link au-target" href="javascript:void(0)" click.delegate="activateStep(eachStep.stepName)" data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-lKVp3L" au-target-id="183" id="contactInformation" aria-current="true">
                            <span data-ph-id="ph-fiju1-default-ph-candidate-profile-v1fiju1-MK4WZK">
                                Contact Information
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li><!--anchor-->

                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of JAWS are you running?

I have an older version, JAWS 2020, and it's reading it correctly.  Your code snippet sounds like this:

```
list 
with 5 items
Account settings Link 
Profile Information Link 
My Applications Link 
Job Alerts Link 
Contact Information Current Link
```

The output is from the speech history window (<kbd>Ins</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>,<kbd>H</kbd>).  Notice the "Current" on the last link because it has `aria-current=true`.

I used <kbd>tab</kbd> to navigate to all the links.

If I use the down arrow to navigate the DOM, I still hear "Current", although it's announced before the link text instead of after it, but that doesn't matter.

```
list of 5 items
• Link Account settings
• Link Profile Information
• Link My Applications
• Link Job Alerts
• Link Current Contact Information
```

JAWS says "bullet" for the bullet graphic symbol.

Comment: I just tested this with JAWS 2022 in Chrome 100 and the speech output is the same as what you've posted, so there doesn't appear to be any difference between the two.